# TFS 2015 "vNext" Build for web project in solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, build

I am trying to achieve setting up a vNext build definition on TFS 2015 (the project is actually a .NET 4.6.1 web project, but I want to use the new TFS build setup). I am struggling with finding documentation on only deploying a specific web project in my solution (2 web projects, 3 class libraries and subsequent tests).

In the XAML build approach, I would specify the .sln and the .csproj file relevant to the build in the Process > 2. Build > Projects input. The "Visual Studio Build" step does not allow for multiple project inputs in the same way, and this seems to be where I am getting stuck. If I only specify the .csproj, Nuget packages do not get restored and the build fails.

Is there any known documentation for deploying a C# web project (.csproj) ONLY via these vNext builds?

MSBuild arguments previously used in XAML Build:

```
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:AuthType=NTLM /p:Configuration=Development /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile="DEV" /toolsversion:14.0 /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile=false
```

The solution I am searching for would accomplish the following:

1. Builds *at the very least* the Web.csproj with project dependencies
2. Restores Nuget packages
3. Transforms web configs
4. Deploys Web project to two separate servers (non-Azure!) via, ideally, web deploy

Thanks in advanced for any help. Hopefully this is possible!

Note: I am not on Azure and Azure is not an option. I know there are tons of documented use case scenarios for Azure users, which is great... but, yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a "NuGet Installer" task at the top of your build definition to restore the nuget packages for your solution and specify the .csproj in Visual Studio Build Step.
[image]

If you want to build the entire solution, you can add following arguments in "MSBuild Arguments":

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

This will create the deploy packages for your projects separately in "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\" folder like following:
[image]

Then you can choose the package for the project you want to deploy. And with the deploy package, you can add two "Command Line" tasks in your build definition and call "Project.deploy.cmd" under "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\" folder to deploy the project to your servers. Reference about deploy from command: [Executing the Command File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356104(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5). Web.config will be transformed by default if you have configured it correctly.

By the way, I recommend you to deploy your projects by using the release management system instead of deploying them in build.